# Functional Programming, Testing Interfaces

Tags: java, functional-programming

I'm stuck with a conundrum with how best to code with a functional programming mindset, while also maintaining readability and testing best practices.

I have an interface like so:

```java
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

import java.util.Collection;

public interface PaymentProvider<S, T> {

    Collection<S> getSubscriptions(LocalDate createOrRenewalDate);

    Collection<T> getTransactions(LocalDate transactionDate);
}
```

As the subscriptions, I can return are only available via the transactions completed on a certain date (external provider limitation), I'm reliant on the response from `getTransactions`. I went down the route of mocking the external provider interfaces which proved time-consuming and frustrating. I feel like this is the wrong course of action. My implementation of the above interface is like so:

```java
public class ExternalPaymentProvider implements PaymentProvider {

    private ExternalProviderGateway ExternalProviderGatewayGateway;

    public ExternalPaymentProvider(){}

    public ExternalPaymentProvider(Configuration configuration) {
        //Configuration....
    }

    public ExternalProviderGateway getProviderGateway(){
        return externalProviderGateway;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Subscription> getSubscriptions(LocalDate createOrRenewalDate) {
        return getSubscriptionsActionedOn(createOrRenewalDate, this::getTransactions, this::searchMultipleSubscriptions);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Transaction> getTransactions(LocalDate transactionDate) {
        ArrayList<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterable<Transaction> search = getProviderGateway().transaction().search(getTransactionSearchRequest(transactionDate));
        search.forEach(transactions::add);
        return transactions;
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    protected List<Subscription> getSubscriptionsActionedOn(LocalDate actionedOn, Function<LocalDate, List<Transaction>> getTransactions, Function<List<String>, List<Subscription>> searchSubscriptions){
        List<String> subscriptionIds = new ArrayList<>();
        getTransactions.apply(actionedOn).forEach(sub -> subscriptionIds.add(sub.getSubscriptionId()));
        subscriptionIds.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
        List<List<String>> subsSubLists = Lists.partition(subscriptionIds, 50);
        List<Subscription> subscriptions = new ArrayList<>();
        subsSubLists.forEach(subList -> searchSubscriptions.apply(subList).forEach(sub -> subscriptions.add(sub)));
        return subscriptions;
    }

    private List<Subscription> searchMultipleSubscriptions(List<String> subscriptionIds){
        ArrayList<Subscription> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterable<Subscription> search = getProviderGateway().subscription().search(new SubscriptionSearchRequest().ids().in(subscriptionIds));
        search.forEach(transactions::add);
        return transactions;
    }

    private TransactionSearchRequest getTransactionSearchRequest(LocalDate searchDate) {
        return new TransactionSearchRequest().createdAt().between(getCalendarDateMinus(searchDate,1), getCalendarDateMinus(searchDate,0));
    }

    private static Calendar getCalendarDateMinus(LocalDate date, int minus) {
        return date.minusDays(minus).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toCalendar(Locale.getDefault());
    }

}
```

My issue is that I've had to make `getSubscriptionsActionedOn` visible so that I can pass my test functional interfaces into the method for testing. While this has allowed testing the function without mocking the externalProvider interface, I've created a code smell by opening the visibility of the function for testing purposes.

I'm wondering what is the functional programming way of testing `getSubscriptions(LocalDate createOrRenewalDate)`? Should I at that point be passing in the functions - ideally I don't want the downstream user having to worry about the externalProviders API's etc.

Please remove if this sort of discussion doesn't belong here.

Comment: Common practice is to create your test in the same package (not necessarily the same jar/directory, but the same package) as the class you are testing. This means methods can be declared package-private for testing purposes, which doesn't change the class contract like `protected` and `public` do.

Comment: "*My issue is that I've had to make `getSubscriptionsActionedOn` visible so that I can pass my test functional interfaces into the method for testing*" Can you explain why? If testing the results of `getSubscriptions` and `getTransactions` is not sufficient to test the implementation, your design is likely poor.

Comment: @Michael by passing in anonymous functions within the test class, it allows me to bypass mocking the external API which means I can test my logic only. If I were to to test both `getSubscriptions` and `getTransactions` I'm mocking and testing the external API interface which doesn't sit right with me. To me, functionally programming should allow you to test the logic that is being written instead of what is being provided. 

I'm open to criticism of the implementation and would appreciate any tips in the right direction,

Comment: @RealSkeptic So my test class package matches my src/main package. I've made that helper function `protected`, by removing it, I think I'd match the direction you're suggesting (and the 1 I was aiming for)

Comment: "*by passing in anonymous functions within the test class, it allows me to bypass mocking*" It sounds like using anonymous functions is almost exactly the same as mocking (probably more specifically "faking", but anyway). I don't see the advantage over using a proper mock. And, as you say, there are clear disadvantages -- you had to mangle the scope.

Comment: @Michael The only benefit to passing in anonymous functions is that I can simply return the responses as I wanted them. When mocking I had to dive into the internal iterator functionality of the API - though I was able to simplify by mocking that by returning an `iterable` ArrayList. Either way, I think I might be over thinking this slightly. 

Thanks for the input :)